# Unit Testing with Mocha unsuccessful

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, chai

I'm familiarizing myself with writing unit test with Mocha and I came across an issue when using
"npm test" command:

```
'MochaChai\testing-callbacks\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '(...)\Desktop\exercisesJS\mocha\bin\mocha.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I know my file.js, file.test.js, node_modules and package.json are correct as I was following an udemy tutorial. It was additionally confirmed when I run: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha "test/**/*.test.js"` directly in terminal and it returned:

```
  calculateSquare
    ✔ Should return 4 if passed 2


  1 passing (11ms)
```

Which I understand as that Mocha works but the problem is in how it's being handled by npm. I went on to check "where npm" and it returned:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
```

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

So, later I checked systems Environmental Variables in search of something out of place but all seemed fine (no NODE_PATH)

Later, I have uninstalled mocha, node_modules, package-lock.json  and installed them back on via npm.
Same result.

Lastly, I have reinstalled Node.js and Visual Studio Code. No change.

I thought it must be something to do with path but I quadruple checked it.

I wonder whether someone had a similar issue and if there's something I could do to understand better what's going on

Answer (score 0):

What a relief, it's solved. The solution was indeed to specify the complete path to the Mocha binary installed in my project's node_modules directory directly in the test script in package.json file. The winner:

```
"scripts": { "test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha './test/**/*.test.js'"}
```

This works because it doesn't rely on the shell to recognize and execute mocha as a command; it only needs node, which is a recognized command as it's installed globally.

The other variations of paths I tried (didn't work for me but maybe it would help someone else...?):

1.

```
"test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha './test/**/*.test.js'"
```

2. 

```
"test": "npx mocha './test/**/*.test.js'"
```

3. 

```
"test": "mocha './test/**/*.test.js'"
```

Simple "test": "mocha" did not do the trick. I've looked into possible cause:

- If Mocha is not properly installed, or the installation is corrupted.
- If there are conflicts with a globally-installed version of Mocha.
- If there are issues with your Node.js or npm installation.
- If the system's PATH settings are not configured correctly.

It seems that this issue arose due to differences in how the operating system or command shell interprets and executes the script commands. In this case, it appears to be related to the Windows environment in which I'm working.

I hope this could be helpful to other newbies out there!